# Node : How to render an image with a relative path?

Tags: node.js

Im sending a password reset email and as its content im rendering html. In my backend (node) I use apth to get the relative path so I can add an image but its not being displayed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

folder structure:
resources/logo.png
resources/email.js

resources/email.js

```
const path = require('path');
const logoPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'logo.png');

const resetPwdEmail= (link, resetPasswordToken) => {
    return (
        `
        <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style>...</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img src=${}/>
      <a class="link" href=${link}/${resetPasswordToken}>reset password</a>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
        `
    )
};

module.exports = {resetPwdEmail};
```

services/index.js

```
...
 htmlContent: resetPwdEmail(link, resetPasswordToken, logoPath),
...
```

Comment: __dirname will provide the directory from which node is running so if your are running your code like node email.js then you can directly do path.join(__dirname, 'logo.png');